# desktop software for web analytics

Tags: analytics, software

I am not a webmaster nor a programmer. I am asking this in order to aid in my research for my Master's dissertation where I have to analyze a website's traffic from a file containing activity on the site for the past 10 years.

What is a great, easy-to-use, and (hopefully) free tool/software that I can install and use on my laptop? I am looking for desktop software, not something to install on a server.

Does anyone know of anything?

---

Added on 21/04/2011
Thanks for the answers. At the moment I still don't have the file so that I cannot give more information.

Comment: What kind of file are you using? What sort of information is in the file? Are you looking for something with graphs. Do you know of a comparable web-app that shows the sort of data you're looking for so that we can recommend similar software that you can download.

If I am getting this right, you wish to import your file into the software which then translates the data into something easier to read - graphs, sections, etc. Is this a correct assumption?

Comment: Can you explain the "desktop sofware" requirement? For example, there are packages(eg. WAMP, MAMP, etc.) that make it trivial to set up a basic web server on your own machine, which them makes all of those web apps "something you can install on your laptop." It seems like you might be unnecessarily limiting your options.

Answer (score 1):

[Splunk](http://www.splunk.com/) is probably worth a look.

You'll have to go into more detail as to what you're looking for to start making requests like "easy to use," I think. 10 years is a **lot** of data to look through and you're not even saying what you're looking *for*. Whatever it is may not be easy to extract in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

The two best known open source packages for this would be [webalizer](http://www.webalizer.org/) and [awstats](http://awstats.sourceforge.net/), while both are often installed on a server they can be run at a command line with no problem, even on Windows. If you want really easy to use there are GUI front ends [available](http://www.tobias-schwarz.net/programmierung/webalizer_guie.html).

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Stat Centric](http://www.statcentric.com). It's web-based. You don't have to install it and really easy to use.